# How to show that $4x^9 -9x^3 + 24x + 13 $ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, substitution

How to show that

$4x^9 -9x^3 + 24x + 13 $ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Since the polynomial is primitive over $\mathbb{Z}$, hence I can show instead that it is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$.

I'm thinking of using $\mod p$ irreducibility test here, but it's still hard to prove it since it's in degree 9. Meaning I will have to check individually that it does not have linear, quadratic, etc. factors.

Do you know of any easier way to prove this?

Comment: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+4x%5E9+-9x%5E3+%2B+24x+%2B+13+mod+11) says that the polynomial is irreducible mod $11$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use $x=y-1$ and Eisenstein for $p=3$.

Since $$-4+9-24+13=-6$$ is not divided by $9$, we are done!

Comment: Ohh i see what you did there. Smart! Thanks!

Comment: How did you think of translating it to x-1, and then coming up with an equation where eisenstein's criterion is readily applicable?

Comment: Because all $\binom{9}{k}$, where $k\neq0$ and $k\neq9$  they are divided by $3$. Also, coefficients $-9$ and $24$ they are divided by $3$ and I checked that $-4+9-24+13$ is nod divided by $9$ and it turned out.